# Checking if a collection is null or empty in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I need to perform a null or empty check on a collection; I think that `!members?.empty` is incorrect.  Is there a groovier way to write the following?

```
if (members && !members.empty) {
    // Some Work
}
```

Answer (score 287, accepted):

There is indeed a Groovier Way.

```
if (members) {
    //Some work
}
```

does everything if `members` is a collection. Null check as well as empty check (Empty collections are coerced to `false`). Hail [Groovy Truth](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#the-groovy-truth). :)

Comment: A more "groovier" way is that for example if you are interested in the maximum age out of the members then you can write the following: members?.age.max()

Comment: Note: `members?.age.max()` blows up with "Cannot invoke method max() on null object" when members is null. You would need `members?.age?.max()`

Comment: @BTakacs I think you mean `members*.age.max()`

Comment: no: GreenGiant's solution is the best:
check `List members = null;` and `List members = [ [age: 12], [age: 24], [age: null], null ]` against both the solutions

Comment: This type of check is working for most of the cases but if your purpose is to check if a variable is null then you might end up to an edge case where the variable is not null but a boolean false

Comment: this solution is perfect for the case where multiple statements needs this check. it works fine for list also for checking not-null and non-empty. 
for single statement I prefer to use null-safe operator as GreenGiant suggests

Comment: Can we test if a parameter is `null` in this way? `if(!members){ // do something }`

Comment: @robothy You will run into issues if you try `!members` if your intention is to do something only when members is `null`. See the examples [here which showcases how Groovy Truth works](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth). It will be better if you explicitly check for null `members == null`

Answer (score 2):

FYI this kind of code works (you can find it ugly, it is your right :) ) :

```
def list = null
list.each { println it }
soSomething()
```

In other words, this code has null/empty checks **both** useless:

```
if (members && !members.empty) {
    members.each { doAnotherThing it }
}

def doAnotherThing(def member) {
  // Some work
}
```

Comment: This code will fail on line 2  null.each will throw an NPE.  The second block of code uses the original user's post.  I think you may have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
!members.find()
```

I think now the best way to solve this issue is code above. It works since Groovy 1.8.1 http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find(). Examples:

```
def lst1 = []
assert !lst1.find()

def lst2 = [null]
assert !lst2.find()

def lst3 = [null,2,null]
assert lst3.find()

def lst4 = [null,null,null]
assert !lst4.find()

def lst5 = [null, 0, 0.0, false, '', [], 42, 43]
assert lst5.find() == 42

def lst6 = null; 
assert !lst6.find()
```

Comment: the collection that has 1 null element is not empty, so your suggestion is wrong

Comment: What if the collection is null?

Comment: def lst6 = null;
assert !lst6.find()  it's correct - no error occurs